# TSQL datetime field doesn't allow updating of the time part of the field from 00:00:00.000 to any other value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

There's a table in a database called table1, one of the columns is called 'date'.

```
select [date] from table1 where autoid=1
```

returns '1999-02-02 00:00:00.000'

When I run:

```
 update table1 set [date] = '2000-01-01 11:11:11.100' where autoid=1
```

then:

```
 select [date] from table1 where autoid=1
```

will return '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'

This happens for all such values in the [date] column in the table.

**If I do a drop and create for this table, however, it works. This is what's really a mystery to me.**

This database has been changed and changed over time, could something be restricting this field and then the create overwrites this restriction etc?

Update:

When I ran a query to try to change the column to date only (out of curiosity)

```
ALTER TABLE table1 alter column [date] date
```

I got the following error message:

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 91
The index 'paydate' is dependent on column 'date'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 91
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN date failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Finding this index in mssql mgmt studio against table1 and doing a script index as -> create to new window etc gives:

```
   /****** Object:  Index [paydate]    Script Date: 01/16/2018 9:44:58 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [paydate] ON [dbo].[table1]
(
    [bking_id] ASC,
    [date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Could this be the issue?

Now as I mentioned before, if I drop and recreate the table, this issue doesn't exist. I noticed that when I did so in another copy of the database, most of the indexes disappear against this table.

What would this index be doing and why isn't it recreated when doing a drop and create? I guess indexes are new territory for me.

Another update:

So I overlooked this due to dropping and creating etc in different dbs. There is indeed a trigger which affects the date column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SetDatesToMidnight_table1]  ON [dbo].[table1]
  FOR INSERT, UPDATE Not For Replication
  AS 
    UPDATE table1
       SET table1.[date] = cast(convert(varchar, table1.[date], 112) as datetime)
     FROM table1 JOIN Inserted 
   ON table1.autoid=Inserted.autoid

GO
```

However, for some reason, dropping this trigger doesn't allow me to update the field as expected?

Comment: Look for triggers. A trigger could easily be overriding the value to force the time portion to zero. (There may also be a check constraint to ensure the value is zero but, by itself, that would error rather than changing the time)

Comment: Are you sure that a field type is datetime and not date?

Comment: So you found the trigger on that table for that column that converts it to a date. I'm surprised it functions without a varchar size, Anyway, what specifically do you mean by "update the field as expected" - what does that mean? Do you get the same issue? As you can see, triggers are usually a bad idea and make things confusing.

Comment: Nick,McDermaid, yes I replicate the issue even after dropping the trigger. Do I need to do something else for this to take effect?

Yeah unfortunately it's not my db design, however i'll try to steer clear from using any.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if your datatype for [Date] column is datetime or probably you have some other issue.It works fine with Update that you have mentioned. Please find below code.

```
create table table1 
(
[date] datetime
)

insert into table1 values ('1999-02-02 00:00:00.000')

select * from table1
--1999-02-02 00:00:00.000

update table1 set [date] = '2000-01-01 11:11:11.100'
select * from table1
--2000-01-01 11:11:11.100
```